# How to update a git superproject that depends on submodule commit under gerrit review?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-submodules

We have a git superproject that has one submodule. The submodule is under gerrit review.

Our problem is that while changes are being reviewed in the submodule, (even if the submodule link to the commit under review has been committed on the superproject) they cannot be retrieved by other developers via 'git submodule update' unless they specifically fetch refs/changes/* in the submodule.

I clearly state that we need other developers to be able to checkout code that is still under review in the submodule. So waiting for the code to be merged is not an viable choice.

Is there a way to enable a developer getting the changes under review in the submodule via 'git submodule update' on the superproject that has the submodule link pointing to the commit under review ?

Answer (score 0):

> they cannot be retrieved by other developers via 'git submodule update' unless they specifically fetch `refs/changes/*` in the submodule.

Yet that seems to be the usual way to get those commit under review.
For instance, the EGit munual section "[Fetching a change from a Gerrit Code Review Server](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_a_change_from_a_Gerrit_Code_Review_Server)" does precisely that:

[image: EGit Gerrit fetch]

This [wiki page](https://tuleap.net/wiki/index.php?pagename=RequestMergeThroughGerrit&group_id=101&pv=1#Review_and_merge_x28.integratorx29.) details the process:

> Merge the patch from gerrit (see the download section in gerrit) it should be something of the sort:

```
git fetch ssh://username@gerrit.tuleap.net:29418/tuleap refs/changes/52/52/8
git merge --no-ff --no-commit --log FETCH_HEAD
```

Since a developer wants to update a submodule (which is supposed to reference a specific commits), he/she can:

- create a `dev` branch from within that submodule, in which Gerrit changes can be merged
- update from time to time that same submodule, and compare the new submodule HEAD with `dev` branch, potentially resetting the `dev` branch to said new updated HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be solved by explicitly fetching the *changes* refs by default:

```
fetch = +refs/changes/*:refs/remotes/origin/changes/*
```

or similar. I'm not sure though if

```
git pull --recurse-submodules=yes
```

will pick it up correctly.